# Sencha Touch side slider navigation menu

Tags: sencha-touch

I am using a side bar slider menu which I got from:
https://github.com/wnielson/sencha-SlideNavigation

I have modified it a bit.
It dragged the UI to the right when it opened, I changed it and now it overlays on the main UI.

This component is working fine on iPhone and some high end devices of Android.

But I am facing some issues in Android 2.2 and 2.3 devices.
The side bar menu never closes and always remain opened.

Answer (score 0):

Please add an "issue" in GitHub so that the author of the repo can answer and solve your query :: https://github.com/wnielson/sencha-SlideNavigation/issues

You can add the issue here :

https://github.com/wnielson/sencha-SlideNavigation/issues